# htaccess rewrite new domain all images wildcard

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I'm trying to make a rewrite because I moved a old site to a sub domain but now the images folder which stayed on its old location but I can't seem to get it to work hope you can help

The old location where all the images is now and should be pointed to is

[http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/citronmåne-opskrift-200x200.jpg](http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/citronma%CC%8Ane-opskrift-200x200.jpg)

wherw "2013/03/citronmåne-opskrift-200x200.jpg" is a wildcard

the location where it is pointing at the moment and is wrong is

[http://test.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/citronmåne-opskrift-200x200.jpg](http://test.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/citronma%CC%8Ane-opskrift-200x200.jpg)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://example.com/wp-
content/uploads/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I tried to rewrite to from another post 
[Rewrite a directory to domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194453/rewrite-a-directory-to-domain)
but I can't get it to work this is the code

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^http://test.example.com/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301]
```